# It is possible to delete components (pipe - ect) from Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

For example if I use the following:

```
ng g c my-new-component:
```

*add a component in application*

He creates the files, the routes and all the history, Angular CLI is very cool. But if at some point I want to delete a component, I have to delete everything by hand and edit the files ect.

I thought maybe using `r` or `remove` this would work, but it is not so:

```
 ng r c my-new-component:
```

*The specified command r is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.*

I have looked at the github but I have not seen anything.

I am sorry for my bad english.

My question is if this is possible, if that's how I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible currently.

We can track this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900